# What files can be .erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I just realized that the `.erb` extension can be added to `.js` files (what a time saver that would have been).  Is there a list of file types that can take advantage of the features of `.erb`? Or is any text file `.erb` capable? I primarily use variable placement e.g. `<%= @user.id %>`

Comment: Be aware that if your JavaScript files are templated, you will lose caching/CDN benefits.  Consider making them generic, and passing user data to them through some mechanism (inline JavaScript just to set data, data attributes, hidden form field, etc.)

Comment: Could you point me to a link so I can read up on this?

Comment: For the advantages of a CDN for static content, see [Yahoo's guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cdn).  To use a CDN cost-effectively, you have to have files that can be shared between a (large) number of users.  If every JavaScript file has a different user id, that doesn't work.  How to pass data is a secondary issue.  Inline JavaScript would be something like `<script>someObject.userid = 1234;</script>`.  A data attribute could look like `<body data-user-id="1234">`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you basically can add an `.erb` extension to any text file and start templating away :)

I personally only tried it on views and JS files, but I don't see why it wouldn't work for other files.